# How to add roles, members, and permissions?

Tags: powershell, ssas

i am trying to add roles and members to a tabular database (cube)

```
$Server = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
$Server.Connect("$server")

$TabDB = $Tabular_Analysis_Server.Databases[$DB]

[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRole] $AddRole = new-Object([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRole])("NewRole1")

$AddRole.Members.Add("member1")

$TabDB.Roles.Add($AddRole)

$AddRole.Update()
```

I get this error:

> new-Object : Cannot find an overload for "ModelRole" and the argument
>   count: "1".
>   and

This `$TabDB.Model.Roles.members` gives me the roles and members just fine

if i try doing it this way:

```
$TabDB.Model.roles.Add("newrole1")
```

I get this error

> Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".

This `$TabDB.Model.roles.Add()` results in

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Add(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRole metadataObject)
void ICollection[ModelRole].Add(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRole item)
```

i found a script here but this is for early cube models (1103 and below) so it doesnt work on tabular models

https://bhavikmerchant.wordpress.com/2010/09/06/adding-ssas-roles-via-powershell/

UPDATE: following the MADMagician's answer, i am able to see this

[image: pic]

Comment: @mklement0 since youve helped me in the past for a similar tabular question, maybe this might be something you can help me with too? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.modelrole?view=analysisservices-dotnet) for the ModelRole class, the constructor doesn't accept any arguments like the older Role class did. You'll have to create a blank ModelRole, update any properties you want, then add it to the ModelRoleCollection.

```
$AddRole = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRole
$AddRole.Name = 'NewRole1'
$RoleMember = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRoleMember
$RoleMember.MemberName = 'member1'
$AddRole.Members.Add($RoleMember)
$TabDB.Model.Roles.Add($AddRole)
```

I don't actually have anything to test on, but the above should create a role, then a member, add the member to the role, then add the role to your database if I correctly understand the documentation that I linked.

As noted, there is not a constructor for ModelRoleMember, instead you have to use the derived classes that do have a constructor:

```
$RoleMember = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ExternalModelRoleMember
```

or

```
$RoleMember = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.WindowsModelRoleMember
```

As for adding permissions you'll want to reference the documentation. It looks like you'll have to make `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.TablePermission` objects, set their properties, and then add them to the TablePermissions property of `$AddRole`.

Comment: while i try it out, what about adding permissions? in the old SSAS, it would be something like this: $PERMISSION = $TabDB.DatabasePermissions.Add($AddRole.ID) ...... $PERMISSION.Read = [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ReadAccess]::Allowed but of course this applied for nontabular

Comment: ok so this one $RoleMember = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRoleMember .............resulted in an error: New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRoleMember.

Comment: and if i ignore adding a member and just skip to $TabDB.Roles.Add($AddRole) .... i get this: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: Right, sorry, it should be `$TabDB.Model.Roles.Add($AddRole)`. As for permissions, did you even look at the documentation I linked? And for creating members it looks like there are two derived classes you have to use depending on if it is a Windows member or an external member. I have updated the answer to address these additional questions.

Comment: what is meant by windows member or external member? for example, if i am simply trying to add a group member to a new role in which that group member is in the active directory of the organization, which would be best?

Comment: Looking at the roles for both classes, the 'External' one says that it is for internal purposes only, so I think you should use the Windows member class for everything.

Comment: is there perhaps an update that must be done before i am able to see the new role? for some reason, $TabDB.Model.Roles displays for me the roles along with the new role, i can see it added in the collection. but i reconnected the server in SSMS and viewing the database, i cant see the new role added. ive read in the past when i am trying to update a connection string for example, i'd have to update...if i do this: $TabDB.Model.Roles.Update() i get error: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRole] does not contain a method named
'Update'.

Comment: ohhh i think i know why its not displaying...member1 is not part of the domain in the org, its just a made up member. also for updating, this is how its done: $TabDB.Update([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions]::ExpandFull)